# Class field not accessible inside of function

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm fairly stupid when it comes to C++ as I'm from a pure Java background with good Python knowledge, but I am trying to make a simple C++ class with a vector referenced in the header file, and access it in a function in the source file. I can access it fine in the constructor, however as soon as I use a function, it apparently doesn't exist according to Eclipse CDT, and the build chain.

Header file (`simulator.h`):

```
#ifndef GAME_PHYSICS_SIMULATOR_H_
#define GAME_PHYSICS_SIMULATOR_H_

#include <vector>

#include "../world/object.h"

class simulator {
public:
    simulator();
    virtual ~simulator();

    void add_object(object o);

private:
    std::vector<object> objects;
};

#endif /* GAME_PHYSICS_SIMULATOR_H_ */
```

Source file (`simulator.cpp`):

```
#include "simulator.h"

simulator::simulator() {
    object o;
    objects.push_back(o);   // Works fine in terms of acknowledging the existence of 'objects'.
}

simulator::~simulator() {}

void add_object(object o) {
    objects.push_back(o);   // Immediately throws error saying 'objects' doesn't exist.
}
```

The funny thing is though, is that I can access things like `int`'s or `std::string`'s fine. As soon as I try to use the vector it breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: At the moment you define `add_object` as a global non-member function.

Comment: Downvote I don't know, but voted for closing anyway as it's likely not useful for future visitors and the title makes it hard to discover anyway. What joachim means: without the `simulator::` the compiler treats it as a normal (as in, not member of a class) function in the global namespace

Comment: @mrAtari Correct. The `object` type is a personally defined class. I want to store an `object` in the `vector`. I'm not so sure I understand what your trying to say...?

Comment: @stijn Thankyou. Now I understand. As for the question, I thought about it as I opened it. Perhaps a more suitable name would fit?

Comment: Possibly, but I wouldn't know how to name it. I'm sure I've seen questions like this here before, but I tried searching for it and couldn't find any, likely because the compiler error is rather vague and doesn't relate to to the fact you forgot to declare the class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `simulator::add_object` since it's a class method, just like you did for the constructor and destructor already.

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe I made this mistake. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 2):

Compared to Java you can define functions outside of the class definition (like in an extra .cpp file, which is usually encouraged to do so), in this case you have to prepend `class_name::` to the function signature.

If not, because your function is not in the class namespace, it becomes a **non-member** function (meaning a function which belongs to no class) and it does not know the `objects` member which is inside your `simulator` class.